# В openvpn не пингуются клиенты и нет доступа к сетевым папкам

Tags: vpn, openvpn

*Добрый день, у меня уже как год поднят VPN, но я ни как не могу настроить общий доступ к сетевым папкам клиента, а так же они не пингуются.*

*Небольшой нюанс, везде адаптер VPN находится в `Неопознанной сети`, и у меня не получалось переместить его в домашнюю сеть*

---

[image: Рисунок]

Так выглядит список устройств. Самое что интересное, **клиент 4** пингуется но нет доступа к общим папкам, а **остальные** клиенты не пингуются и нет доступа к их сетевым папкам. **Проблема решается отключением брандмауэра для общественной сети.** Может подскажите какие исключения надо внести в брандмауэр чтоб клиенты из под **сервера** пинговались и был доступ к их сетевым папкам? А подключение к клиентам из под сервера по RDP работает без проблем.

```
Сервер(ping) -->  Клиент 1 =          не работает
Сервер(сетевые папки) -->  Клиент 1 = не работает
Сервер(RDP) -->  Клиент 1 =           РАБОТАЕТ!!!

Сервер(ping) -->  Клиент 2 =          не работает
Сервер(сетевые папки) -->  Клиент 2 = не работает
Сервер(RDP) -->  Клиент 2 =           РАБОТАЕТ!!!

Сервер(ping) -->  Клиент 3 =          не работает
Сервер(сетевые папки) -->  Клиент 3 = не работает
Сервер(RDP) -->  Клиент 3 =           РАБОТАЕТ!!!

Сервер(ping) -->  Клиент 4 =          РАБОТАЕТ!!!
Сервер(сетевые папки) -->  Клиент 4 = не работает
Сервер(RDP) -->  Клиент 4 =           РАБОТАЕТ!!!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Для ping разрешить: icmp echo
- Для общих папок: udp 137, 138 tcp 139, 445

Comment: Общие папки заработали, а что за `icmp echo`

Comment: Это ping. http://ping-test.ru/icmp

Comment: Как его добавить в исключение?

Comment: Зависит от операционки. Ответ в первой строке google: https://help.keenetic.com/hc/ru/articles/213966229-%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-ping-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D0%9E%D0%A1-Windows-8-10

Comment: На клиенте с **Windows 7** решил командой в командной строке с повышенными правами: `netsh firewall set icmpsetting 8`

Comment: Я сейчас проверил их по отдельности, оставив только это правило `tcp 139 445` все работало

Comment: Используемые порты и протоколы зависят от настроек и используемых служб. Я написал для "общего случая".